# Struct initialization during class definition

Tags: c++

I have a problem with struct initialization during class definition. I know that C++ standard not allows to define variables during class definition except `static const` variables.

In my case i have generated C-code with initialization of lot of structures. All POD variables in this code (pure C-code) is global. I want to make this POD local so i am try to include this code in a class and need to solve problem of struct initialization. Basic example of generated struct is:

```
// generated C-code
struct G { int a; };
G GS = {0};
```

If we try to put it in a class we can say:

```
class CL{
public:
    struct G { int a; } GS = {0}; //error
};
```

And we have an error:

```
error C2059: syntax error : '{'
error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
```

Ok. Some changes.

```
class CL{
public:
    struct G { int a; } GS;
    CL() { GS.a = 0; }
};
```

Works fine. But in my case i have a lot of structures which contain lot of fields. I do not want to make many changes in generated code. How about `static const`?

```
class CL{
public:
    static const struct G { int a; } GS; //ok
    static const struct GT { int a; } GST = {0}; //error
};
```

Maybe i can make all structures as `static const` structures and initialize them? How i can solve my problem?

Comment: `static const` integral, actually.

Comment: You either need a static class member or you don't. It cannot be seen as a solution to initialization because it means something *totally* different to a plain data member.

Comment: Just for curiosity, is your whole goal to zero-initialize any members in any POD structs you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the initialization of a static member struct in a .cpp file, for example:

```
// cl.h
class CL{
public:
  static const struct G { int a; } GS; 
  };

// cl.cpp
const CL::G CL::GS = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solution will be acceptable for you

```
// your header
template<typename T> T Create();

#define DECLARE_CREATE(STRUCT_TYPE, INITIALIZER)\
    template<> STRUCT_TYPE Create<STRUCT_TYPE>()\
{\
    STRUCT_TYPE GS = INITIALIZER;\
    return GS;\
}\

// generated C-code
struct G { int a; };
// replace G GS = {0};
DECLARE_CREATE(G, {0});


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    G g = Create<G>(); // use initialized structure
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you define a constructor for the structure to initialize it.

```
class CL
{
public:
    CL() {};
    ~CL() {};

    struct G
    {
        int a;
        G() { memset(this, 0, sizeof(G)); }
    };

    G GS;
};
```

Comment: I don’t think `memset` on `this` is *ever* a good idea. At best, it’s totally useless here (just initialise the members!).

Comment: All members of the structure are POD, and the user request is to not  alter the generated code to initialize all the fields one by one.

Comment: Frankly, that’s not an excuse to write bad code. In fact, the proper solution would be to change the generator accordingly, or, if that’s impossible, to post-process the generated code. Also, putting a `memset` in vs. an initialiser list doesn’t seem such a big difference.